# use custom built opencv along with cv_bridge

Tags: opencv2, cmake, ros-hydro

[image: Rosanswers logo]

After updating to Hydro, the method mentioned in [this answer](http://answers.ros.org/question/61923/how-to-use-newer-versions-of-opencv-in-fuerte/) does not work anymore, where I have to depend on cv_bridge to transfer sensor_msgs::Image to cv::Mat. The cmake will strike a warning:

```
  Cannot generate a safe runtime search path for target my_custom_node
  because there is a cycle in the constraint graph:
    dir 0 is [/usr/local/lib]
      dir 1 must precede it due to runtime library [libopencv_calib3d.so.2.4]
    dir 1 is [/opt/ros/hydro/lib]
      dir 0 must precede it due to runtime library [libopencv_videostab.so.2.4]
```

And the built binary is indeed linking the /opt/ros/hydro/lib/libopencv_xxx.so (checked with ldd).

So what is currently the **right way** to use custom built opencv, while I have dependency like `cv_bride` which depends on the `opencv2` package?

Thanks for any suggestions.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/173892/use-custom-built-opencv-along-with-cv_bridge/) by [K Chen](https://answers.ros.org/users/1551/k-chen/) on ROS Answers with karma: 391 on 2014-06-18

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Did you try downloading cv_bridge source, modify package.xml and CMakeLists.txt to replace dependency with libopencv*.so?

---

Originally posted by [130s](https://answers.ros.org/users/875/130s/) with karma: 10937 on 2014-06-19

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0